# How to spawn other programs within perl script and immediately continue Perl processing?

Tags: perl, multiprocessing

How to spawn other programs within perl script and immediately continue Perl processing (instead of halting until the spawned program terminates) ?
Is it possible to process the output coming from the spawned program while it is running instead of waiting it to end?

Comment: [Perl FAQ 8: How do I start a process in the background?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background-), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711520/how-can-i-run-perl-system-commands-in-the-background, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133910/how-can-i-fire-and-forget-a-process-in-perl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `open` for this (to run the program `/bin/some/program` with two command-line arguments):

```
open my $fh, "-|", "/bin/some/program", "cmdline_argument_1", "cmdline_argument_2";
while (my $line = readline($fh)) {
    print "Program said: $line";
}
```

Reading from `$fh` will give you the stdout of the program you're running.

The other way around works as well:

```
open my $fh, "|-", "/bin/some/program";
say $fh "Hello!";
```

This pipes everything you write on the filehandle to the stdin of the spawned process.

If you want to read and write to and from the same process, have a look at the [`IPC::Open3`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Open3) and [`IPC::Cmd`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Cmd) modules.

Answer (score 1):

To run a program in the background and "continue going" all you have to do is add "&" at the end of the command (I'm assuming you are using Linux). example:`system("command &");` note that `system("command", "arg1", "&");` will NOT work, since it will pass the "&" to the command and not to the shell. You can simply print the output of a command by doing: `print system("command");`

Comment: When you down vote write a comment why it is not useful. I think this is a valid answer because there were two questions, one is to process the output other is to continue the rest of the code without waiting for the command to finish. I will be glad to know the reason if i am wrong

Comment: system() doesn't return the output of a command, but its return code/exit status. The child process inherits stdin/out/err from the process doing the call to system(). Also, I don't like to encourage people to use one-argument system() - it comes with scary security risks.