# MultiProcessing via Perl on windows

Tags: perl, multiprocessing

I wrote this code that should open several process , the problem is its work on linux well but when i execute it on windows its just create one process !!. is this possible to create multiprocess on windows with perl ?

```
$j = ARGV[0];
for($i=1; $i<=$j; $i++){
system("perl example.pl word.txt.$i &");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/8157848/725418

Comment: @TLP : This is a Windows question, I don't think it's a duplicate

Answer (score 6):

`&` is a *nix thing. An explicit `fork` in Windows will do it.

Bear in mind that Windows implementations of Perl *emulate* forking using threads, so that may be another option.

```
my @pids;
for my $i (1 .. $j) {

    my $pid = fork;

    unless ( $pid ) {  # Child
        system("perl example.pl word.txt.$i");
        exit 0;
    }

    push @pids, $pid;
}

waitpid $_, 0 foreach @pids;
```

Answer (score 3):

Better `fork` from the enclosing Perl script and then call `system` in the child process without the trailing `&`. `wait` will be needed in the parent as well.

Because the argument of `system` is parsed by the system shell, you will encounter different behaviour from the Windows shell than from Bash, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier to use the START command (Windows Batch command) than to fork processes.  The downside is that it will open multiple DOS windows.

```
system "start perl example.pl word.txt.$i";
```